# Error running `meteor update --patch`

Tags: javascript, meteor

After running `meteor update --patch` to update Meteor from 1.4.2.3 to 1.4.2.7, the following error is seen:

```
=> Errors while initializing project:

While selecting package versions:
error: No version of standard-minifier-js satisfies all constraints: @1.2.1, @2.0.0
Constraints on package "standard-minifier-js":
* standard-minifier-js@1.2.1 <- top level
* standard-minifier-js@2.0.0 <- top level
```

Any idea how to fix this issue?

Comment: You could try upgrading patch by patch using `--release` arg. From 1.4.2.3 to 1.4.2.4, then to 1.4.2.5 and so on. This could help to trace down the issue

Comment: @Nyxynyx have you been able to solve the issue?

Comment: @DenisGorbachev Eventually got it to work, think I deleted Meteor completely then reinstalled